# 2nd grade 1970s child's story with illustrations including an injured fox and another animal being scolded

Tags: identification-request

The story I am thinking of appeared in my 2nd grade (73-74) reading textbook and was set in winter and featured a group of animals.  It was heavily illustrated and showed an injured fox bleeding from the leg.  One of the other animals was responsible and was scolded by the other animals.  Lots of snowy scenes.  Does anyone know what this story might have been?   Another story in the same textbook was a child's version of Florence Nightingale's biography.

Comment: Was this a *short* story, given that there were multiple stories in the same textbook? Could it have been an excerpt from a longer work? I'm thinking of the Farthing Wood series, specifically [The Fox Cub Bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_Cub_Bold), but that was a full-length novel.